# Wrong date while using the NSDateFormatter() and NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

Tags: swift, date, calendar, formatter

I have a function, which creates a label with date in a format "dd.MM"

```
func dateLabel(date: NSDate)->UILabel {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: date)
        let month = components.month
        let year = components.year
        let day = components.day
        let calendarForFormat = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

        //formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "\(NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().abbreviation!)")
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM"

        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(calendarForFormat!)

        let dateLabel = UILabel()
        dateLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 10)
        dateLabel.textColor = mainWhiteColor
        dateLabel.text = dateString

        return dateLabel

    }
```

The interesting thing is that sometimes it returns the wrong date. You can see it on a picture below:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So which is the wrong date. Where is it ?

Comment: If you look at the date it is 2015-06-23 and if you look at the day it is 24 and date string is "24.06" and it should be "23.06"

Comment: NSDate is independent of time zone, it just keeps track of the time elapsed from certain time period. You should make sure that your formatter has correct timezone to be able to display the time correctly.

Comment: Yes I've tried to set the time zone but it didn't help

Comment: Which timezone are you in? Most probably "2015-06-23 21:08:00 UTC" *is* 24.06 in your timezone.

Comment: Martin R it's a good point) I didn't think about it) And I guess you are right! Thank you! That simple. Thank you!